# projects and gitolite remote on same machine

Tags: git, gitolite

I'm trying to setup a new development server that also will serve as a git remote host.

Some people will be developing on the server and push to the remote and some use there own machine and push to the server when there done.

We are using gitolite to facilitate those who work on there own machine so the can push and pull with there private key.

The problem now is that those working on the server itself have a hard time cloning, pushing and pulling. There are always permission problems with are hard to get around.

It just doest feel like this is the way it should work, so i was wondering if our setup is right or are we just using it in the wrong way (maybe we don't even need gitolite?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gitolite` isn't really designed to also support people cloning on the local machine, since it does all of its permissions magic via ssh hooks.

You could just have those working on the server clone via SSH anyways, to make sure everyone's process is paralleled. Thus, instead of the people on the local machine doing this:

```
git clone /path/to/repo
```

have them do this:

```
git clone git@localhost:path/to/repo
```

(And set up their ssh keys in gitolite as you do for everyone else.)

Comment: Do i just have to copy there private keys in ~/.ssh or is there something else that i have to do? The keys are setup in gitolite. If i do the gitolite@localhost:repo it asks for the password of the gitolite user

Comment: They need to have their private key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (that's the default path ssh looks at, iirc).

Comment: i keep getting 'gitolite@localhost's password:'

Comment: Type `ssh-add -l` then and see if it displays the proper key. If it doesn't, type `ssh-add` to add it. If it does, check on the gitolite configuration end and make sure the public keys are added properly.

Comment: had to run /usr/share/gitolite/gl-compile-conf again to get the key in gitolite to work